# Restrict which functions can modify an object

Tags: r

I have a variable in my global environment called `myList`. I have a function that modifies `myList` and re-assigns it to the global environment called `myFunction`. I only want `myList` to be modified by `myFunction`. Is there a way to prevent any other function from modifying `myList`?

For background, I am building a general tool for R users. I don't want users of the tool to be able to define their own function to modify `myList`. I also don't want to myself to be able to modify `myList` with a function I may write in the future.

I have a potential solution, but I don't like it. When the tool is executed, I could examine the text of every function defined by a user and search for the text that will assign `myList` to the global environment. I don't like the fact that I need to search over all functions.

Does anyone know if what I am looking for is implementable in R? Thanks for any help that can be provided.

For a reproducible example. I need code that will make the following example possible:

```
assign('myList', list(), envir = globalenv())
myFunction <- function() {
    myList <- c(myList, 'test')
    assign('myList', myList, envir = globalenv())
}
userFunction <- function() {
    myList <- c(myList, 'test')
    assign('myList', myList, envir = globalenv())
}
myFunction() # I need some code that will allow this function to run successfully
userFunction() # and cause an error when this function runs
```

Comment: I don't think one should be so restrictive - you should look at S3 classes and maybe the best solution would be to almost have your own data structure that and methods unique to that class. Because your data is not created by the function, but modified - the initial input will always be free to do whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need the [`modules`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/modules) package.

Basically, each unit of code has its own scope.

e.g.

```
# install.packages("modules")
# Load library
library("modules")

# Create a basic module
m <- module({
    .myList <- list()
    myFunction <- function() { 
        .myList <<- c(.myList, 'test')
    }

    get <- function() .myList
})
# Accessor
m$get()
# list()

# Your function
m$myFunction()

# Modification
m$get()
# [[1]]
# [1] "test"
```

Note, we tweaked the example slightly by changing the variable name to `.myList` from `myList`. So, we'll need to update that in the `userfunction()`

```
userFunction <- function() {
    .myList <- c(.myList, 'test')
}
```

Running this, we now get:

```
userFunction()
# Error in userFunction() : object '.myList' not found
```

As desired.

For more detailed examples see [`modules` vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/modules/vignettes/modulesInR.html).

The alternative is you can define an environment (`new.env()`) and then lock it after you have loaded `myList`.

Answer (score 1):

This is all around a bad idea. Beginning with assignment into the global environment (I'd never use a package that does this) to surprising your users. You should probably just use S4 or reference classes.

Anyway, you can lock the bindings (or environment if you followed better practices). You wouldn't stop an advanced user with that, but they would at least know that you don't want them to change the object.

```
createLocked <- function(x, name, env) {
  assign(name, x, envir = env)
  lockBinding(name, env)
  invisible(NULL)
}

createLocked(list(), "myList", globalenv())


myFunction <- function() {
  unlockBinding("myList", globalenv())
  myList <- c(myList, 'test')
  assign('myList', myList, envir = globalenv())
  lockBinding("myList", globalenv())
  invisible(NULL)
}

userFunction <- function() {
  myList <- c(myList, 'test')
  assign('myList', myList, envir = globalenv())
}

myFunction() # runs successfully
userFunction() 
#Error in assign("myList", myList, envir = globalenv()) : 
#  cannot change value of locked binding for 'myList'
```